# jquery - cancel an alert that occurs from another part of the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very unique/strange situation I am in.  Within my project, on my master template, I have the following situation towards the bottom of the page....

```
...
<body>
<div>blah...blah</div>


/*FOR CURTAIN REASONS, I CAN'T TOUCH THIS SCRIPT*/
<script type="text/javascript">
var ccPopup = window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank'); 
if (!ccPopup) alert('Your browser has popup blocker enabled. Please disable it and try again');
var _fV4UI = true;
</script>
/**/

/*BUT I CAN CONTROL ALL THINGS BELOW...*/
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-javascript-file.js"></script>
/**/

</body>
..
```

I basically want to prevent (!ccPopup) from doing it's alert message, which occurs every time the page loads.  How can I prevent this alert action from occurring inside of my-javascript-file.js?  If I can't do it there, I also have the flexibility to add javascript in the `<head>` of my page if need be...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the head, you'll have to hijack the alert function:

```
showAlert = false;
myAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(msg) { 
    if (showAlert) { 
        myAlert(msg); 
    } 
}
```

And then you can toggle whether or not alerts appear by changing the value of showAlert;

```
showAlert = true; alert("hi"); //alerts "hi"
showAlert = false; alert("hi"); //nothing happens.
```

You could also do something like:

```
window.alert = function(msg) { 
    if (msg != "Your browser has popup blocker enabled. Please disable it and try again") { 
        myAlert(msg); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can I place the showAlert condition after the problem script, within document.ready? or is that pointless...

Comment: To prevent the alert, you HAVE to hijack the alert function before the other code runs - that code isn't set up to wait for page load, so will be executed immediately. Which means to prevent it, you have to run before (either in the head, or in the body before the other script).  But you could easily turn alerts back on in `document.ready`.

Comment: I was able to do as you suggested.  It all worked out perfectly.  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any other alerts on the page, you might be able to get away with doing something like this.

```
  window.alert = function() {
      return false;
  }
```

Not pretty, but it might work.

Comment: Just don't forget to restore it to original one after that code block is executed. You may need alert for other uses

Comment: but will this only work in the head of the page, or can i load this within my js file towards the bottom of the page, on document.ready?

Comment: You'll want to run it before the alert for the ccPopup. You have access to the head, right?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Asking sincerely, what would be the best way to restore it?

Comment: @mikehomme see accepted answer.  U store reference to the original function in a temp variable. That answer runs original from within hijacked function, but u might as well assign that temp variable back to window.alert once hijacked function is no longer needed

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an ugly hack, but you could redefine `window.open()`:

```
window.open = function() { return true; };
```

later:

```
var ccPopup = window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
if (!ccPopup)
    alert('...');
```

The first line should be in the `head`, before the other snippet.

http://jsfiddle.net/0abgvrtf/

Comment: this would be so awesome if we could do this for the window.open that has a curtain string!